# Java 14 Syntax error on token "record", record expected

Tags: java, eclipse, java-14, java-record

I'm engaged in building something in Java 14.

I wrote a class named for PersonInJava14 shown below.

```
package recordexample;

public record PersonInJava14(String name, String gender, int age) {}
```

However, it throws an error like this.

```
Syntax error on token "record", record expected
```

The project is based on Java 14 and can be done essential settings to run it in Java 14.

Here is my setting part.

[image]

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Did you `--enable-preview`?

Comment: @Johannes Kuhn I share my settings part.

Comment: No problems on my end with those settings. You did install [Java 14 support for eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-14-support-eclipse-2020-03-415)?

Comment: @Johannes Kuhn I already installed Java 14 Support for Eclipse 2020-03 (4.15) before building these kinds of code.

Comment: You need to both return a record and define it.

Comment: if `record` is a class/enum you should follow the Java naming convention and capitalize it

Comment: Worked for me using the Eclipse [wizard](https://imgur.com/a/4h5afPg) Go to File > New > Record

Comment: The only other google hit is this bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=558718 when `--enable-preview` is missing fixed last week. Absolutely sure those are the settings for the right project.

Comment: @JoSSte - Yes.  But `record` is not a class or enum name in this case, so your advice is not apropos.

Comment: I suspect this is an Eclipse issue.  Try compiling with `javac --enable-preview <filename>.java` using JDK 14.

Comment: It complies via command (java --enable-preview <filename>.java) but there is an issue in Eclipse.

Comment: you get a similar error when you write a method inside the main method.

Comment: This features is available with Java 15 in Eclipse:

Go to Project Properties -> Java Compiler: Check "Enable project specific settings". Then check "Enable preview features for Java 15". Press "Apply and Close".

There should be no error anymore.

I used Eclipse version 2020-12.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with your Eclipse. You can download another version of Eclipse or try compiling it by console with the following command: `javac.exe PersonInJava14.java --enable-preview`

Hope you can solve you problem ;)

Comment: I believe, nearly four years later, that the OP has already upgraded both Eclipse and JDK so not sure how much your answer will help him or anyone else who may come across your answer.